# How can I work on fakeOutbreak data and export them?

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand how to work  on fakeOutbreak data from outbreaker r package and how to replicate these analyses on different data.

Is this a dataframe? How can I export to excel? How should I transform a normal db?
Thank you

Comment: You can use `class(any_object)` to determine the type of object , you can use `WriteXLS `function from the WriteXLS package to convert to a excel sheet and to convert it(data.frame) into a db you can use `RMySQL::dbWriteTable`

Comment: Using ```class(fakeOutbreak)``` I obtain ```> class(fakeOutbreak)
[1] "list"```

Comment: it is a list....Infact its list of list, you can access these. `fakeOutbreak$dat`  is list and `fakeOutbreak$dat$dynam` for list of list....If you want to determine names in a list to refer objects using `$` sign then you can see `names(fakeOutbreak)` to get name of objects, `names(fakeOutbreak$dat)` to get the objects from objects inside `fakeOutbreak$dat` ...